# dotenv doesn't get imported by python

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm making a discord bot, and I used env file to hide the token. however, [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R3VFh.png) popped up. How do I fix it?

Comment: Did you install python-dotenv?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you might not have it installed?

https://pypi.org/project/python-dotenv/

or type `pip install python-dotenv` in your terminal.

You should also make sure you've installed it to the correct python version you're running as well if you keep running into issues.